# React, trying to check if a value is present in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array `licenseKeys` in React state, and need to push to it all new values of `lisenceKey`'s that user types to input fields. It works, but when I'm trying to check whether value of new key is present in array `this.state.licenseKeys.includes(this.state.licenseKey)`, I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`.
I tried to use an arrow function with `some` instead, but I got the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined`. 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
 if (localStorage.getItem("formData")) {
  this.state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData"));
} else {
  this.state = {
    ppks: [],
    alert: false,
    ipState: "",
    portState: "",
    userNameState: "",
    passwordState: "",
    licenseKey: "",
    licenseKeys: [],
    licenseKeysObject: []
   // refreshButttonDisabled: true
}    
    }

 licenseKeysSetter = () => {
    if (this.state.licenseKey !== "" && this.state.licenseKeys.includes(this.state.licenseKey) === false){          
        this.setState({
            licenseKeys: [ ...this.state.licenseKeys || [], this.state.licenseKey]              
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.licenseKeys);            
        });
    }   
  }
```

```
.....
<ul>
      {ppkData.map((item, index) => {   
       if (item.model === "8l") {  
        return (
          <div className="ppkCard" key={index + 1}>

          <form>
          <div className="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div className="input-group-prepend">
            <span className="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Enter License Key</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text"
                 className="form-control"
                 placeholder="000-000-000-000-000-000" 
                 onChange={this.licenseKeysHandler}
                 value={this.state.licenseKey || ''} 
                 aria-label="Small" 
                 aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>       
        <button type="button" onClick={this.licenseKeysSetter} >Save</button>     
        </form>
.........
```

```
 licenseKeysHandler = (event) => {      
    this.setState({licenseKey: event.target.value}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.licenseKey);
    })      
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the full component code for more context?

Comment: What is value of that array inside licenseKeysSetter() , please add console.log there and tell.

Comment: Try `this.state.licenseKey`intead of `this.state.licenseKey !== ""`

Comment: Do you use constructor? If not, than remove this. from state declaration

Comment: @Yurii I insist on console to the log `this.state` before the `if` statement. ))

Comment: You should show us what is `this` in your code. Without knowing the context it is hard to get where is the issue.

Comment: an array ``this.state.licenseKeys`` is undefind before if statement...

Comment: Maxime Girou same

Comment: If you define your state out of `constructor` drop `this` part. just use it as `state = ...`

Comment: @Yurii what's in `licenseKeysHandler` as I see you are calling it right before you save the result.

Comment: @Daniyal Lukmanov  no, handler is doing fine. When I remove code ``&& this.state.licenseKeys.includes(this.state.licenseKey) === false)`` from ``if`` statement, the code is working! The problem is - I have an array ``this.state.licenseKeys`` of ``undefind`` when I check whether a value is in array...

Comment: add licenseKeysHandler code to your question please

Comment: @Pavlo Kovchuk I did

Comment: @Yurii also add `setState` please

Comment: @ Daniyal Lukmanov done

Comment: `this.state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData"));` is the most likely place that sets `this.state.licenseKeys` to `undefined`. can you please `console.log(localStorage.getItem("formData"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `localStorage` does not include all keys necessary in the state (e.g. after a new version release), you can separate initial state from loading localStorage like this:

```
class MyComponent() {
  state = {
    ppks: [],
    alert: false,
    ipState: "",
    portState: "",
    userNameState: "",
    passwordState: "",
    licenseKey: "",
    licenseKeys: [],
    licenseKeysObject: []
  }  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData")))   
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed code like this, and it works fine for me...

```
 licenseKeysSetter = () => {
    //console.log(this.state.licenseKey);
    console.log(this.state.licenseKeys);
    //console.log(this.state);
    if (this.state.licenseKeys === undefined) {
        if (this.state.licenseKey !== "" ){         
        this.setState({
            licenseKeys: [ ...this.state.licenseKeys || [], this.state.licenseKey]              
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.licenseKeys);            
        });
    } 
  } else {      
    if (this.state.licenseKey !== "" && !this.state.licenseKeys.includes(this.state.licenseKey)){            
        //console.log(this.state.licenseKeys);
        this.setState({
            licenseKeys: [ ...this.state.licenseKeys || [], this.state.licenseKey]              
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.licenseKeys);            
        });
    }  
    }   
  }
```

Comment: It's better to identify the actual issue instead of updating the working code.